# Can a Svelte component be embedded in a non-Svelte app?

Tags: embed, svelte, svelte-component

I work in a group that has several projects, and each one is written in a different framework. We would like to have some self-contained widgets whose behavior and appearance are standard, but can be used in any of the systems. I thought Svelte sounded like a good option, because it doesn't require adding a framework on the front end. But I can't find anything that says Svelte is usable within other systems; it has to be an all-Svelte app to have Svelte components.

Is that correct? Or is there some way to embed a Svelte component into another system?

Comment: Svelte components can also be compiled to custom elements (aka web components). More here: https://svelte.dev/docs#Custom_element_API

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can include a Svelte component anywhere as soon as you have the reference to the DOM element you want to append your Svelte component.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

//MyComponent is the compiled component
new MyComponent({
  target : container
});
```

See the Svelte docs: https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api

But then you have some limitation on how you can handle the state if you have multiple components included like that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want even wider compatibility and just include the component with a `script` tag, you can use the `document.currentScript` property and compile the Javascript into standalone script with rollup.js or webpack:

```js
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.svelte';

var div = document.createElement('DIV');
var script = document.currentScript;
script.parentNode.insertBefore(div, script);

const myComponent = new MyComponent({
    target: div,
    props: { propname: 'some value' },
});
```

You can compile a nice package with rollup if you have `rollup-plugin-svelte` and `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` packages installed into your project. Below is a suitable rollup.config.js for this, added further notes into comments:

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
    input: 'embed.js',
    output: {
        format: 'iife',
        file: 'dist.js',
    sourcemap: false,
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({ emitCss: false, }),
        resolve({ browser: true, dedupe: ['svelte'] }),
    ],
}
```

Comment: A more in-depth tutorial available on [my website](https://codeandlife.com/2021/03/06/easy-to-embed-svelte-components/) with tool specifics. Most stackoverflowers should be adept enough with the above answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can export the component as webcomponent using `<svelte:options tag="component-name"/>`;